# Code needs debugging.I am not able to figure out how the values are rounded off

Tags: python, loops, average

why the code is not able to round off correctly in some test cases which are not perfectly divisible

```
 #!/bin/python

import math
import os
import random
import re
import sys


# write your code here
def avg(*nums):
    len1=len(nums)
    count=0
    for i in range(len1):
        count=count+nums[i]
    average=count/len1
    return round(average,2)

    
if __name__ == '__main__':


    
    fptr = open(os.environ['OUTPUT_PATH'], 'w')
    
    nums = map(int, raw_input().split())
    res = avg(*nums)
    
    fptr.write('%.2f' % res + '\n')

    fptr.close()
```

for example :

Input (stdin)

7

Your Output (stdout)

7.00

Expected Output

7.00

this test case is correct because digits after decimal is 0 but fo test cases like below:
Input (stdin)

2 5

Your Output (stdout)

3.00

Expected Output

3.50
another example
Input (stdin)

-95 -45 -56 48 36 79 -83 -16 -95 -57 1 -95 -61 30 9 -56 18 62 -99 61 40 -32 -69 92 -33 -82 -81 70 21 62 46 7 95 -24 10 66 24 73 16 41 -91 -55 -42 -84 -54 -80 -45 27 -27 -26 -58 -47 88 30 22 -66 46 -68 -24 98 28 11 37 69

Your Output (stdout)

-6.00

Expected Output

-5.98

here it is not rounding off correctly please help me with debugging my code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
def avg(*nums):
    len1=len(nums)
    count=0
    for i in range(len1):
        count=count+nums[i]
    average=count/len1
    return round(average,2)
```

Variables count and len1 are both int. So, if "2 5" on input then you have "2/5", integer division, lost digits after dot. You need cast both or one of variables cast to float.
Examples:

```py
count = 0.
```

or

```py
average = float(count) / float(len1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you're using `raw_input`, I'm guessing this is Python 2, where dividing an integer by another integer results in an integer.

So here:

```
nums = map(int, raw_input().split()) # list of integers
# ...

len1=len(nums)  # integer
count=0  # integer
# ...
average=count/len1  # also integer
```

`average` is an integer.

To solve this, convert one of the operands to `float`:

```
average=count / float(len1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your variables are of type `int`.

So when you do the division you miss out the actual precision. `13/2 = 6.5` but because all the types are `int` the result will be `6`, you are missing out the `0.5`

Then when you do the `round` to just converts the result which is actually an `int` into a `flaot` and you always end up `x.00`

Add a `float(variable)` to solve your issue